# How does this recursive Python code work?

Tags: python, recursion

I came across this recursive function that's supposed flatten a dictionary:

```
def flatten(data, prefix='', separator='.'):
    """Flattens a nested dict structure. """
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        return {prefix: data} if prefix else data

        result = {}
        for (key, value) in data.items():
            result.update(flatten(value,_get_new_prefix(prefix, key, separator),
            separator=separator))
        return result

def _get_new_prefix(prefix, key, separator):
    return (separator.join((prefix, str(key))) if prefix else str(key))
```

it's also supposed to be fed with this data:

```
nested = {
 'fullname': 'Alessandra',
 'age': 41,
 'phone-numbers': ['+447421234567', '+447423456789'],
 'residence': {'address': {'first-line': 'Alexandra Rd','second-line': '',},
 'zip': 'N8 0PP',
 'city': 'London',
 'country': 'UK',
 },
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how it works and particularly how the "prefix" parameter works and in what case it will not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The `flatten()` function builds the path down the tree, where the names in the path are separated by the separator.  The prefix is added to the beginning of that path.

`prefix` is only "empty" if you set it to `None`.  That will have the effect of suppressing the prefix.

For example, compare the output of this:

```py
[print(k, ' = ', v) for k,v in flatten(nested, prefix='xxx', separator='/').items()]
```

...with this:

```py
[print(k, ' = ', v) for k,v in flatten(nested, prefix=None).items()]
```